# How to use MSBuild validate property?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

In [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017) there is a property named `validate`, and he accepts a scheme as a parameter.

What is this `schema`?

How to write it?

Comment: Likely the default is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Xml\Schemas\1033\Microsoft.Build.xsd, also because this seems to be referred to in the source code as default: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/MSBuild/ProjectSchemaValidationHandler.cs line 46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use MSBuild validate property?

This property `validate` is used to specify a schema file `.xsd` to validate the project file.

**How to use it:**

Just like the document said:

> If you don't specify schema, the project is validated against the
>   default schema.
>
> If you specify schema, the project is validated against the schema
>   that you specify.
>
> The following setting is an example:
>   `-validate:MyExtendedBuildSchema.xsd`

**What is this schema?**

> XML Schema is commonly known as XML Schema Definition (XSD). It is
>   used to describe and validate the structure and the content of XML
>   data. XML schema defines the elements, attributes and data types.
>   Schema element supports Namespaces. It is similar to a database schema
>   that describes the data in a database.

Check the document [XML - Schemas](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_schemas.htm) and [XML Schema Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) for some more details.

Note: The default Schemas file for MSBuild: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Xml\Schemas\1033\Microsoft.Build.xsd`.

Hope this helps.